# Last 2 month record in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, records

I try this SQL query to get current total and also last 2 months records and current month record means total 3 months..

```
Select distinct 
tblRv.Owner,
(Select Count(*) as total from tblvv WHERE MasterID =tblRv.ID and Name <> '') 
as currentdata
from tblRe
inner join tblRv 
On tblRe.RID = tblRv.RID
WHERE 
tblRe.StartDate between dateadd(m, -2, getdate()) and getdate() and 
//tblRe.StartDate >= '2016-07-01 00:00:00' AND 
//tblRe.EndDate <= '2016-07-08 23:59:59' 
  and tblRe.Region = 'uk' and
tblRv.Owner='Roh' 
order by tblRv.Owner
```

when i exe this show me like this

```
OwnerName     currentdata
Roh               1
Roh               2
Roh               3
Roh               5
```

and  when i check individually write query and check from date `2016-07-01` and todate `2016-07-30` dates then this show me data `3` and `2016-06-01 00:00:00` and `2016-06-31 23:59:59`  show me data `1` and `2016-05-01 00:00:00` ,`2016-05-31 23:59:59` show me data `0`
so i want data like this

```
owner july june may 
roh   3     1   0
```

also when there will be current month i.e. aug then data must display last 2 months i.e.june july

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a pivot query where the three columns to be pivoted are the current, previous, and previous previous month in your data set.  Note that I had to rewrite your query to remove the subqueries in the `SELECT` clause, because this makes it impossible to do aggregation of those columns.

```
SELECT tblRv.Owner,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tblRe.StartDate = GETDATE() THEN t.total ELSE 0 END) AS currMonth,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tblRe.StartDate = DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())
             THEN t.total ELSE 0 END) AS prevMonth,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tblRe.StartDate = DATEADD(m, -2, GETDATE())
             THEN t.total ELSE 0 END) AS lastPrevMonth
FROM tblRe
INNER JOIN tblRv
    ON tblRe.RID = tblRv.RID
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MasterID, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM tblvv
    GROUP BY MasterID
    WHERE Name <> ''
) AS t
    ON tblRv.ID = t.MasterID
WHERE tblRe.StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() AND
      tblRe.Region = 'uk' AND
      tblRv.Owner = 'Roh' 
GROUP BY tblRv.Owner
ORDER BY tblRv.Owner
```

Comment: this show error. Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: what is t after where

Comment: I don't see the error.  `t` is an alias for the subquery on table `tblvv`.

Comment: ok i put where clause above group by & when i excute this show currMonth 0 ,prevMonth 0 , lastPrevMonth0  means .. owner(roh) currMonth 0,prevMonth 0,lastPrevMonth0  0

Comment: but i have data i.e 3,1,0

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
         tblRv.Owner
        ,DATENAME(MONTH,tblRe.StartDate) as [Month]
        ,ISNULL(SUM(total),0)   as currentdata
from tblRe
INNER JOIN tblRv ON tblRe.RID = tblRv.RID
LEFT  JOIN (
            Select Count(*) as total ,MasterID
            from tblvv 
            WHERE Name <> ''
            GROUP BY MasterID
            ) tblvv 
ON tblvv.MasterID =tblRv.ID 
WHERE tblRe.StartDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) 
 AND  tblRe.EndDate   <= GETDATE()
 AND  tblRe.Region = 'uk' 
 AND  tblRv.[Owner] ='Roh' 
GROUP BY tblRv.Owner
        ,DATENAME(MONTH,tblRe.StartDate)
order by tblRv.[Owner]
```

Comment: this show nothing .. only this show owner,month,currentdata as a header..

Comment: @user6628729 can you setup a sql fiddle? Its really difficult to tell what your data is like and how the query should be written.

Comment: This won't give the desired output because you didn't pivot, but I agree with moving the count query into a join.

Comment: but how i get data when i try in jsfiddle

Comment: @M.Ali this show data but .. this show july current data 3 and june current data 10 and may data 6 .. but i have data 3,1,0.. and this shows 3,10,6

Comment: @M.Ali check this plz